# Implementing a SOAP web service

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I have a WSDL definition for a SOAP service and I have successfully generated *.cs file from it using SvcUtil.

Implementing client is quite straightforward - I just need to call the necessary functions from the generated *.cs and that's it.

Implementing server seems more complicated. As I understand I need to implement an interface from the generated *.cs and then use some magic to turn it into the web server.

But I don't need a new web server, I already have a web server written in C# which already has many functionality unrelated to the SOAP service that I need to implement. I don't want to create another web server but I want my SOAP service to be just a part of my existing application (server), that is my server can answer e.g. requests `http://example.com/request1`, `http://example.com/request2` etc. and I want this SOAP service to be just `http://example.com/request3`.

Since HTTP is already handled by my server I don't need .NET to handle it for me, basically my server can accept client connections and call the necessary handler based on the URL. I have a handler for SOAP request which looks approximately like this:

```
MyResponse HandleSOAPRequest(MyRequest request)
{
    // 1. parse soap message from request.body
    // 2. process it
    // 3. generate response, serialize it in SOAP format and return it
}
```

The question is - can I rely on WSDL definition and .NET libraries to do it?

Currently I'm parsing SOAP request using XDocument and manually extract fields from it and serialize using simple string concatenation. Using .NET built-in functions to serialize or parse XML doesn't work. That is if I try to serialize response from an object of the class defined in the generated *.cs file then produced XML is different from what is expected by the protocol, similarly, if I try to parse request as an object of the class defined in the generated *.cs file I get error because XML parser expects different format. This applies to both the SoapFormatter and XmlSerializer.

Since .NET can implement client this means that everything that is necessary to parse and serialize SOAP messages is already implemented, I just need to figure out a way how to use this functionality.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.aspx) for ServiceModel wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Could you say something more about your server? I assume you mean an IIS, right? Actually all you have to do is to deploy the WebService dll to your IIS, perhaps customize do cofiguration and you're done.

Comment: @t3chb0t, no it is not IIS, it is my own server written in C#.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I need to implement a server, client is only for testing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to start the service via the `ServiceHost`:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourService));
host.Open();
```

(I assumed here the configuration will come from the `app.config` and will not be setup in code like in the linked example below.)

[How to: Expose a Contract to SOAP and Web Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196(v=vs.110).aspx)

The only drawback of this is that the application has to run with admin rights or otherwise a weird cofiguration is necessary.

Comment: So, this way it will start a separate web server? I will then need to redirect request from my web server to this new server.